# Azure Digital Twins-Iot Hub Issue

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

How can I get access of iot hub created through azure digital twins services? I am only getting **"connection string"** of that iot hub after provision by running given sample demo from Microsoft documentation. **If I want to connect devices** to this iot hub, how can i do that?

Comment: Be more specific, add examples of things you have tried and didn't work.

Comment: as iot hub is not in not present in my subscription if i want to connect any device to this iot hub how do i connect it ? and how do i get the respective connection string to use it further

Comment: [{"id":"6f865ff1-e8bd-4c72-8989-22b72e6e4572","name":"Child Device 1","typeId":14,"parentSpaceId":"0d302cfe-3e94-4445-9bac-9c093ed52747","subtypeId":13,"statusId":12}]here i am getting only id of the device if i want connection string of the device how do i get that?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that, Azure Digital Twins is in Public Preview. Currently, there is no direct access to the IoT Hub created along with Digital Twins. However in GA we will have the ability for you to bring your own/directly create & associate your own.

Comment: ok then how do i get the connection string of connected devices with this iot hub?

Comment: You can get the IoT Hub device connection string from the Management API. Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/concepts-device-ingress#get-the-iot-hub-device-connection-string-from-the-management-api
Also, see this issue for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809507/how-can-i-get-the-connection-string-for-iot-hub-in-azure-digital-twin

Comment: Please let me know if you need further help. You can accept the response as answer if it helps.

Comment: thank you for the response. yes i am getting this iot hub connection string through swagger api. If i want  to have device connection string which connected to iot hub how do i approach for this?